# Hide provinces in MapBox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm using `MapBox` to show a map to the user. As can be seen in the following picture, the map shows province and region outlines (dashed lines in e.g. China, Russia and India). Is there a way to **remove the province outlines** so that only the country outlines and city names remain?

[image: Map with province outline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the background tile layer. It is png tiles served from a server, so unless they have a set without those borders, no, there is no way to remove them.

However, you can custom roll your own tiles using a variety of methods.

Mapbox methods:
[TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/). 
[Mapbox studio](https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#welcome).

Google Maps method:
[Google Maps API styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Or you could look for other alternatives that fit your needs. Leaflet has a [plugin](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) with a good list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter out all borders or only region borders. Try to play with filtering.

**Code 1**

```js
map.on('data', () => {
  // Disable all borders
  var borders = ['admin-0-boundary', 'admin-1-boundary', 'admin-0-boundary-disputed', 'admin-0-boundary-bg'];
  borders.forEach(function(border) {
    map.setLayoutProperty(border, 'visibility', 'none');
  });
});
```

or **Code 2**

```js
map.on('data', () => {
  // Disable all borders
  //var adminLayers = ['admin-0-boundary', 'admin-1-boundary', 'admin-0-boundary-disputed', 'admin-0-boundary-bg'];
  // Disable regions
  var adminLayers = ['admin-1-boundary', 'admin-0-boundary-disputed'];
  adminLayers.forEach(function(adminLayer) {
    map.setFilter(adminLayer, ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "US"], false, false]);
  });
});
```

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDjHk.png)